# numbering from up to down

Tags: numbers

I want to translate a sentence from Persian to English, the sentence I want to say is:

> The children should **numbers from up to down** and conversely

but I am not sure does it correct?

Comment: Your question sort of made sense—until I got to *conversely*, and then it made no sense at all. Are you talking about counting down and counting up?

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean "counting in order" and "counting in reverse order."

"Counting down" is fairly frequently used to mean "counting in reverse order," but "counting up" is less frequently used to imply the order in which things are counted and sometimes simply is used as a synonym for "counting" as a process for determining the number of elements in a set.

Answer (score 0):

> The children should count in ascending and then descending order.

Comment: Please [edit] to include an explanation of *why* this is correct; answers without explanation do not teach the patterns of the language well. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta.